# Why Downcasting throws Exception?

Tags: java, classcastexception, downcast

In java:

```
Base b = new Base();
Derived d = (Derived)b;
```

throws `ClassCastException`. Why? Why downcasting throws `Exception` here? I could not figure out the reason.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let me rename your classes to make things more clear.  `Base` -> `Animal`.  `Derived` -> `Cat`.

Just because you're an `Animal` doesn't mean you're a `Cat`.  You could be a `Dog`.  That's why it's illegal to cast an `Animal` into a `Cat`.

On the other hand, is every `Cat` an `Animal`?  The answer is "yes".  That's why you *could* write code like this:

```
Animal animal = new Cat();
```

or

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
Animal animal = cat;
```

Also what's worth noting is you *can* do this:

```
Animal animal = new Cat();
Cat cat = (Cat) animal;
```

The reason you can do this is that your `animal` variable is actually referencing a `Cat` instance.  Therefore you're allowed to cast it back into a variable that references a `Cat`.

Comment: +1 because it's the first time I see an example of `Cat` instead of `Dog`.

Comment: Animal animal = new Animal();
Cat cat = (Cat) animal;  How can animal be safely downcast to cat?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast a derived class as the base class. You may assign `b` as either a `Base` or a `Derived`, but you may only assign `d` as a `Derived`. Long story short, you may only assign a variable declared as `Base` a value that is of the same type (`Base`) or a derived type.

This is okay (I'm just using `new` as an example, what matters is the data types):

```
Base b = new Base();
Base b = new Derived();
Derived d = new Derived();
```

But this is not:

```
Derived d = new Base();
```

This is the way that inheritance works

Answer (score 1):

To downcast in Java and avoid run-time exceptions, take a reference of the following code:

```
if (animal instanceof Cat) {
  Cat cat = (Cat) animal;
}
```

Here, Animal is the parent class and Cat is the child class.

**instanceof** is a keyword that is used for checking if a reference variable is containing a given type of object reference or not.

Answer (score 0):

A derived class inherits the *behavior* from its super class. Hence, casting a sub-class object to a super-class reference works since ***the derived class object is capable of fulfilling the contract defined by the super-class***.

On the other hand, a super-class (by the very way you define the classes) clearly doesn't implement most of the methods present in the sub-class. Well, that's why you extended the super-class in the first place - to extend its implementation.

So, casting a super-class object to a sub-class type is an ***inherently unsafe operation*** because the base class object cannot fulfill its sub-class' contract completely.